# Multiple bitmap calls not working

Tags: bitmap, racket

I'm new to the Racket language. I have an assignment in which we must program a game that rolls two dice and uses their sum to determine a winning throw. When I run it, it should say for example:

```
You threw X and Y which makes a throw of Z.
(X, Y, and Z are number values)
```

However, for full credit we must use a graphical representation so I'm attempting to use a picture of each dice face. Right now I just want to output this:

```
(image of first die) and (image of second die)
```

My code looks something like this:

```
(define (showDice)  
  (bitmap "path_of_first_die_image")
  (display "and")
  (bitmap "path_of_second_die_image"))
```

When I run it however it only prints the "and" and the last image, like this:

```
  and (image of second die)
```

Comment: `bitmap` isn't part of Scheme; nor is `require` nor `2htdp/image`. Suggest removing the Scheme tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scheme, only the last value of the `define` is the return value.
The `display` call is not a return value.
The first bitmap is not displayed on-screen because it is not a return value and is not explicitly displayed. The `"and"` is not a return value but is explicitly displayed.
The second bitmap is a return value and therefore is displayed automatically by DrRacket. (Actually Scheme and Lisp all do that, but displaying images is a specialty of DrRacket.)

To have a single return value containing the three elements, you can write:

```
(define (showDice)
  (list
    (bitmap "path_of_first_die_image")
    'and
    (bitmap "path_of_second_die_image")))

(showDice)
```

The three elements are displayed by DrRacket, but the output is not very nice to the user.
So if you want more control on how the values are displayed on the screen, you can `display` the values on the screen yourself, without returning values and without relying on DrRacket catching the return values to display them, here is what you can do (working example):

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image)

(define (showDice)
  (display (bitmap icons/b-run.png))
  (display " and ")
  (display (bitmap icons/stop-16x16.png)))

(showDice)
```

Note that the return value of `showDice` is the value of `(display (bitmap icons/stop-16x16.png))`, which is none (or, more exactly, `#<void>`) because `display` is define to not return a value.

(Also note that in Scheme functions are usually named in all lower case with dashes between words, so one would name the function `show-dice`.)

Comment: I ended going a different way about it (I used frame% and message% to display everything) but thanks a lot! I will definitely look into your suggestion for the next one.